# Forbidden 403 - Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, capistrano

Some help would be appreciated - keep getting Forbidden 403 error.
Nginx configuration:

```
listen       80;
server_name  www.xxx.com;   
passenger_enabled   on;
#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
root   /home/deploy/xxx.com/current;
```

I've deployed with Capistrano, and it was successful (cap deploy)
I've googled and not found much help, from those that I tried.
Secondly, I've removed my "public" folder, and enabled my "route" in routes.rb.

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

Origionally I had the "public" folder in place, but it kept going to "index.html", not the Rails /Home. I've tried this locally and it works perfectly with "rails server" on localhost:3000.

It almost appears as if NGINX does not now how to find or serve up the Rails pages.

Ps. I did review StackOverflow, not luck there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that this line `root   /home/deploy/xxx.com/current;` should be `root   /home/deploy/xxx.com/current/public;`.

Comment: Yeah tried that as above :) I've removed the "public" because it kept referencing index.html which is incorrect.

Comment: Have you deleted `index.html`? If not, you should delete the file.

Comment: Ok will try that, let you know in a moment

Comment: Nice try, but no luck - if "public" is there, it appears to still look for "index.html" *cries*

Comment: It works this way in production. You have to point your web server to the public page of your application. When i made a deploy to the cloud i followed this tutorial that helped me a lot. http://infinite-sushi.com/2011/01/deploying-a-rails-app-to-a-linode-box/

Comment: What do you get in access.log for nginx and what shows up in the rails app log? That should show you what's being resolved by both...

Comment: check the file permissions of the application , try changing them.

Comment: At the moment, error.log is saying - error] 19615#0: *1 "/home/deploy/xxx.com/currenti/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory); And access log; 41.29.243.112 - - [01/Sep/2012:13:17:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.82 Safari/537.1"
41.29.243.112 - - [01/Sep/2012:13:18:20 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
69.175.54.106 - - [01/Sep/2012:13:56:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 168 "-" "-"

Comment: Changed permissions entire app folder to 755. Will look at the tutorial thanks MurifoX

Comment: Found a problem - seems in config/environments/production.db I did not have pre-compilation turned on for images, so there was an internal error loading an image_tag......oooh progress

Comment: Next error was Javascript Runtime - Mac OS X seems to have one by default, so need to add on production server; gem 'therubyracer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yihhaaaaa ok got it!

The problem seemed to be two things as mentioned in the comments:

> (a) Pre-compilation error; "images" were not loading. Went into
> config/environments/production.db and turned on "true" for asset
> compilation.
>
> (b) Second thing was because I was developing on Mac OS X, a Javascript Runtime is included by default, whereas my production
> Ubuntu not so. So I added to GemFile - gem "therubyracer".

And what do you know it works!
The key was looking in the production.log (/home/deploy/xxx.com/current/log/).
That shall tell all.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons related to this error, please check this post for more details: http://thelazylog.com/posts/how-to-fix-403-fobidden-issue-on-nginx-rails-application